# NodeJS Error: Cannot find module './lib/oauth'

Tags: node.js, module

After cloning my test site from github and succeeding to remove the default version of node on my raspberry pi 3 and installing V8.5.0, I ran `npm install` and `npm install nodemon -g`. Now however I am unable to run my script due to an error:

> module.js:529
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module './lib/oauth'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:476:23)
>       at Module.require (module.js:568:17)
>       at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>       at Object. (/home/pi/Projects/EncodedB0t/node_modules/request/request.js:28:13)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)

I've tried adding `npm install oauth --save` to no avail and haven't been able to find an answer online.

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit: added my github repo, https://github.com/TheWalkingM3m3/EncodedB0t

Answer (score 0):

Try run `npm install request --save`. Then rename `oauth.js.example` in your root directory on `oauth.js`. It's works in my case.

Comment: The request fixed it, can you explain why and how this error occured?

(And I'm smart enough to rename the example oAuth file :P)

Comment: In the file `/node_modules/request/request.js:28:13` there is a line `OAuth = require('./lib/oauth').OAuth`, but required file doesn't exists in `/node_modules/request/lib` folder. I don't know why and how :). But I assumed that the explicit installation of this module will fix the situation.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks a lot for your help! Otherwise I'd have been stuck for hours and hours.